# Get new post count for each topic according to user last view

Tags: php, mysql, count

I cant figure out how to do the mysql query for it. 
I have mysql table for topics (id,name) and posts (user,topic,post,time) and user last topic views (topic,user,time)

I need to get the new post counts that are written after user last viewed the topics.

First thing should be probably to get the last views and add it to an array, then get array of topics? What kind of mysql query should i make that includes data from these two arrays?

The result should be (id=>count):

```
array(1 => 2, 2 => 0, 3 => 15)
```

Then i can make:

```
first topic (2)
second topic (0)
third topic (15)
```

Comment: is that always 3 'topics' in array ? - is it constant

Comment: no, its different number.

Comment: I will check all your answers, thank you

Answer (score 0):

topics

```
id |    name    |
-------------------
 1 |    bla     |
 2 |    lala    |
```

posts

```
topic_id |   user   |        time         |
--------------------------------------------
  1      |   X      | 2013-08-09 12:00:00 |
  1      |   Y      | 2013-08-09 13:00:00 |
  2      |   Y      | 2013-08-09 12:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------
```

user_views

```
   topic_id | user_id  |    posts  |   read   |
   ---------------------------------------------
     NULL   |    NULL  |   NULL    |   NULL   |
   ---------------------------------------------
```

When first the user opens the forum, you need to add the new posts

```
INSERT INTO `user_views` (`topic_id`, `user_id`, `posts`, `read`)
VALUES (
(SELECT `id` FROM `topics`), 
$_SESSION['user_id'], 
(SELECT COUNT(`topic_id`) FROM `posts` GROUP BY `topic_id`),
0
);
```

So, it became:

user_views

```
   topic_id | user_id  |   posts   |    read   |
   ---------------------------------------------
     1      |  5       |     2     |     0     |
     2      |  5       |     1     |     0     |
   ---------------------------------------------
```

The user open topic_id = 1, and so the posts became read automatically (you maybe are not tracking how each post is read). So on the exact opening of the topic:

```
UPDATE `user_views` SET `read` = (SELECT COUNT(`topic_id`) FROM `posts` WHERE `topic_id` = $_GET['topic_id'] AND user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

It now became:

user_views

```
   topic_id | user_id  |   posts   |    read   |
   ---------------------------------------------
     1      |  5       |     2     |     2     |
     2      |  5       |     1     |     0     |
   ---------------------------------------------
```

Now a new post is made in topic_id=1:

posts

```
topic_id |   user   |        time         |
--------------------------------------------
  1      |   X      | 2013-08-09 12:00:00 |
  1      |   Y      | 2013-08-09 13:00:00 |
  2      |   Y      | 2013-08-09 12:00:00 |
  1      |   Z      | 2013-08-09 14:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------
```

The user opens the forum, it checks if there are new topics to insert posts and view, if not, only do this:

```
    UPDATE `user_views` SET `posts` = (SELECT COUNT(`topic_id`) FROM `posts` WHERE `topic_id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `topics` WHERE `id` = `posts`.`topic_id`) AND user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

So it became:

user_views

```
   topic_id | user_id  |   posts   |    read   |
   ---------------------------------------------
     1      |  5       |     3     |     2     |
     2      |  5       |     1     |     0     |
   ---------------------------------------------
```

To retrieve unread posts you can do:

```
SELECT `topic_id`, `user_id`, `posts`-`read` as 'unread' FROM `user_views` WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

This will return:

user_views

```
   topic_id | user_id  |   unread  |
   ----------------------------------
     1      |  5       |     1     |  // 3-2
   ----------------------------------
     2      |  5       |     1     |  // 1-0
   ----------------------------------
```

So from the last visit, the user now has only 1 new post in each topic.

I hope you got the logic. Maybe there's easier way with storing already viewed posts in session or cookie, but it seems unreliable for me, so a new table is ok, I guess.

How to first insert the new topics when the user visit the forum, depends on your app logic.

Ofcourse, the queries might have some errors, I tried to make them as workable as I can. They are only examples, and you have to make them fittable with your app, i.e. to not inject $_GET or $_SESSION directly in the query.

P.S.: I would suggest to have autoincrement key column `id` in `POSTS` table, so it will perform better, also querying will be against `id`, not topic_id i.e. `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM posts`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT posts.topic, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM posts 
         WHERE posts.`time` > views.`time` 
           AND posts.`topic` = topics.`id`) AS counts 
  FROM posts 
  LEFT JOIN topics 
    ON topics.`id` = posts.`topic`
  LEFT JOIN views 
    ON topics.`id` = views.`topic`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```sql
SELECT t.id, t.name, COUNT(*) new_posts
  FROM posts p JOIN topics t
    ON p.topic_id = t.id LEFT JOIN views v
    ON t.id = v.topic_id
   AND v.user_id = 1
 WHERE p.time > COALESCE(v.time, 0)
 GROUP BY t.id, t.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

Sample output:

```
| ID |   NAME | NEW_POSTS |
---------------------------
|  1 | topic1 |         2 |
|  2 | topic2 |         1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8808/1)** demo

Comment: @user1365447 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?